# Jquery Problems with set an id attribute and use the id for a scroll function

Tags: jquery, attributes, set, scrollto

**I made a simmple example at fidle.**
https://jsfiddle.net/johi123/0xdvq3wp/10/

**from my project:**
Always say me there is no id set. 
**url:**
***https://hiti-seo.com/seo-suchmaschinen-optimierung/news/seo-news.html#MUM - Eine neue Ära der Suche beginnt***

**console message:**
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).offset() is undefined

I don't know why it"s say Problem is at $('')offset, the problem is the second headline id ="#MUM - Eine neue Ära der Suche beginnt" who i set.

Comment: Please see [ask]. You need to show some code here, not at another site.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should give the name of the attribute:

`var wichid=$('li:eq(0)').attr();`

=>

`var wichid=$('li:eq(0)').attr("id");`

Comment: my problem is that i cant use scroll function to an seted id.  If i would set the id direct in html it would work. But i need to use the headlines as id .  One work arround could be to reload the site if this is still working in 2022 but has perfomance issues. Thats why i need help cause i run against this wall not the first time :-))

Answer (score 0):

Its the empty space in the id , that was the Problem .

Anyway thank you for try to help.